# await for function with callback

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-2017

I'm playing with streams and async/await functionality. What I have so far is:

```
let logRecord = ((record, callback) => {
     console.log(record);
     return callback();
});

let importCSVfromPath = async((csv_path) => {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var parser = parse();
        var input = fs.createReadStream(csv_path);
        var transformer = transform(logRecord, {parallel: 1});

        input.on('error', (err) => {
            reject(err);
        });
        input.on('finish', ()=> {
            resolve();
        });

        input.pipe(parser).pipe(transformer);
    });
});
```

Now I want to replace logRecord with importRecord. The problem is that this function has to use functions that are already part of the async stack.

```
let importRecord = async( (record) => {
    .......
    await(insertRow(row));
});
```

What's the right way to do this?

Comment: What is providing the `async` and `await` functions here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's slightly more complicated than this - node.js streams are not adapted (at least not yet) to the es7 `async`/`await` methods.

If you'd like to develop this on your own, consider writing a class derived from [Readable stream](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_implementing_a_readable_stream). Implementing a promise based interface is quite a task, but it is possible.

If you're however fine with using a permissive licensed framework - take a look at [Scramjet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/scramjet). With it your code will look like this (most of the example is parsing the CSV - I'll add a helper in the next version):

```
fs.createReadStream("file.csv")        // open your file
    .pipe(new StringStream())          // pass to scramjet
    .split("\n")                       // split by line
    .parse((line) => line.split(","))  // convert lines to arrays
    .map(async (line) => {             // run asynchrounous mapping
        await importRecord(line);      // import log to DB
        return logRecord(line);        // return some log for the output
    })
    .pipe(process.stdout);             // pipe the output wherever you like
```

I believe it's exactly what you're looking for and it will run your record imports in parallel, while keeping the output order.